# Set padding for cells of a specific row (not all cells) and set vertical center alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

## The context

I'm trying to create a table that meets the following conditions

1. the padding on all cells from the first row must be bigger than the default padding.
2. the content of all cells must be vertically center aligned.

Regarding the condition no. 1: I know how to change the padding on all cells but don't know how to do it for all cells of an specific row without causing this effect on all the other rows (see document below)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{2}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding the condition no. 2: I know how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|}
   \hline a & \lipsum[1][1-2]
\\ \hline \lipsum[2][1-2] & b
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## The question

How can I create a table that meet condition no. 1 and condition no. 2?

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{a}` instead of `a`, `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{b}` instead of `b` to center them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use zero width rules piped into a zero width m-column to set the height of the rows. In addition, I define a new column type, `M`, which vertically and horizontally centres its content.

In example 2, I have defined a new command `\rl`, which allows you to set the row height individually.

**Example 1 - same height rows**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15pt}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{M|}>{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}m{0pt}}
   \cline{1-3} a & b & j &
\\ \cline{1-3}  a & b & j &
\\ \cline{1-3}  a & b & j &
\\ \cline{1-3} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - different height rows**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15pt}}
\newcommand{\rl}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1pt}}


\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{M|}m{0pt}}
   \cline{1-3} a & b & j & \rl{16}
\\ \cline{1-3}  a & b & j &
\\ \cline{1-3}  a & b & j &\rl{30}
\\ \cline{1-3} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't meet the condition no. 1. The reason I posted this question is because I want to find a way to set the padding for the cells of an specific row without affecting the cells from the other rows.

Answer (score 4):

In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have two keys `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` and a key `cell-space-limits` for their conjonction.

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.18 of 2021-07-15), it's possible to fix the value of those parameters for a single row with the command `\RowStyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{MMM}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=1mm]
some text & here also some text & text, text, text and text \\
some text & here also some text & text, text, text and text \\
\RowStyle[cell-space-limits=0pt]{}
some text & here also some text & text, text, text and text \\
some text & here also some text & text, text, text and text \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The package `nicematrix` also provides a key `hvlines` which draw all the rules.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use  `arraystretch`  to have vertically centered cells contents, as it asymmetrically expands the height and depth of cells. A better way uses package `cellspace`, which defines a *minimal* vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

Here is demo, with `\cellspacetop-bottomlimit` chosen so that the solution with `arraystretch` and the solution with `cellspace` result in tables of the same height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{8.5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{8.5pt}

\begin{document}

{\def\arraystretch{2}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
   \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline a & b & c
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, it seems that in answer  you not load your solution (the code for the right table on image)

Comment: @Zarko: I did, but there may be an optical effect due to b having an ascender, in the middle column.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but your MWE doesn't reproduce showed image. In it is missing code for the right table (a solution for use `cellspace` package. Or I not understand your answer :-(

Comment: @Zarko: Oh! A copy-paste accident. I  misunderstood what you  meant. I should have checked. Thank you!

Comment: This answer doesn't meet the condition no. 1. The reason I posted this question is because I want to find a way to set the padding for the cells of an specific row without affecting the cells from the other rows.

Answer (score 0):

Both conditions are met with this approach

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu, stackengine}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{|m{80pt}|m{80pt}|m{80pt}|}
\hline

\addstackgap[80pt]{a}
& b
& \lipsum[1][1-2]
\\ \hline

A
& B
& C
\\ \hline

\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]